# Include repeated measures in lavaan mediation model

Tags: r, r-lavaan

How can I account for within-subject dependencies in this model? I've got a 2x2-within-subjects design for which I performed an anova and now need to do a mediation analysis. Where does the term for repeated measures go?

```
library(lavaan)
library(dplyr)

id <- rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 4)
IV1 <- rep(c(2, 1), each = 2, times = 3)
IV2 <- rep(c(1, 2), times = 6)
DV <- c(4,3,2,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,3,5)
M1 <- c(1,1,1,3,3,5,3,4,3,4,2,4)
M2 <- c(3,4,4,4,4,5,4,5,4,4,4,4)
df2 <- data.frame(id, IV1, IV2, DV, M1, M2)

model <- "
  # Regression paths from IV to mediators
  M1 ~ a1*IV1 + a2*IV2 
  M2 ~ b1*IV1 + b2*IV2 
  
  # Regression paths from mediators to DV
  DV ~ c1*M1 + c2*M2 + c3*IV1 + c4*IV2
  
  # Indirect effects
  direct_IV1 := c3
  direct_IV2 := c4
  indirect_IV1 := a1*c1 + b1*c2
  indirect_IV2 := a2*c1 + b2*c2
  total_IV1 := a1*c1 + b1*c2 + c3
  total_IV2 := a2*c1 + b2*c2 + c4
"

fit <- cfa(model, data = df2)
parameterEstimates(fit) %>% filter(op == ":=")
#>            lhs op            rhs        label    est    se      z pvalue
#> 1   direct_IV1 :=             c3   direct_IV1 -0.209 0.261 -0.798  0.425
#> 2   direct_IV2 :=             c4   direct_IV2  0.001 0.337  0.004  0.997
#> 3 indirect_IV1 :=    a1*c1+b1*c2 indirect_IV1  0.209 0.547  0.382  0.703
#> 4 indirect_IV2 :=    a2*c1+b2*c2 indirect_IV2  0.332 0.587  0.566  0.572
#> 5    total_IV1 := a1*c1+b1*c2+c3    total_IV1  0.000 0.602  0.000  1.000
#> 6    total_IV2 := a2*c1+b2*c2+c4    total_IV2  0.333 0.602  0.554  0.580
#>   ci.lower ci.upper
#> 1   -0.721    0.304
#> 2   -0.660    0.663
#> 3   -0.863    1.280
#> 4   -0.818    1.482
#> 5   -1.179    1.179
#> 6   -0.846    1.513
```

Comment: cluster-robust *SE*s and tests are available by adding the `lavaan()` argument `cluster = "id"` in this example.  But if the repeated measures are temporal/longitudinal, then unmodeled autoregressive effects might bias your results.  Cole & Maxwell have written papers on longitudinal mediation, where repeated measures are stored in wide format.